# Enforce only one valid copy of data in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class representing a temporary file. Roughly, it looks like this

```
class TempFile {
private:
    std::string mName;
public:
    TempFile() :
        mName(std::tmpnam(NULL)) {}
    ~TempFile() {
        //File automatically deleted when this goes out of scope
        std::remove(mName.c_str());
    }
};
```

If I return this from a function, it's my understanding that a copy will be made, and the original deleted, so I won't have the file anymore.

I could heap-allocate and return a pointer, but I very strongly prefer a solution without raw pointers. I am not allowed boost or C++11.

My best idea is to define a misleading copy constructor:

```
TempFile(TempFile& rhs) {
    mName = rhs.mName;
    rhs.mName = "";
}
```

This should work, but it's evil and will almost certainly cause problems later.

Comment: You can write your own version of lighweight [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: Make copy ctor and assignment operator private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot use c++11 then you might use `std::auto_ptr`. Its deprecated now, so if your company ever start using C++11 you will get deprecation warnings. Solution would be to write your own shared ptr:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77c9a0f2e0e3d42f

```
#include <memory>

struct X{

  ~X() {
    std::cout << "~X";
  }
};

std::auto_ptr<X> foo() {
  std::auto_ptr<X> px(new X);
  return px;
}

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<X> px = foo();
}
```